# java class files in current directory?

Tags: java, classpath

How "java" knows the class file to execute without setting the class path.ie.,Does it check in the current directory by default or we need to set the class path for current directory too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It checks the current directory first. If the class is not found, it searches for that class in the class path.

> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the `CLASSPATH` variable or using the `-classpath` command-line option overrides that default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include `"."` in the new settings. [[source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)]

Comment: is it correct .I read in some book like it wont check the current directory explicitly we need to set class path for current directory too...!~

Comment: It's up to the vendor that writes the JVM. The standard implementation from Sun/Oracle looks in the current working directory first. Some oddball runtime could do it differently.