# specifying log4j in classpath

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I believe this is how I can compile and run a file that uses external library. I'm using Windows.

```
top level directory
|
|-log4-1.2.17.jar
|-MyApp.java
|-com
     |-foo
          |-Bar.java
```

Compiling

```
javac -cp log4j-1.2.17.jar;. com\foo\Bar.java
javac -cp log4j-1.2.17.jar;"com\foo";. MyApp.java
```

Executing

```
java -cp log4j-1.2.17.jar;"com\foo";. MyApp
```

Compiling itself failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple batch script, for compiling all your project

```
set COMPILED_CLASSES=.\
set TEMP_FILE=temp
dir .\*.java /s /B > %TEMP_FILE%
javac -classpath log4j-1.2.17.jar;%COMPILED_CLASSES% -d %COMPILED_CLASSES% @%TEMP_FILE%
rm %TEMP_FILE%
```

add it to top level dir and run
**EDIT**
step by step

```
javac ./com/foo/Bar.java -classpath log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

next

```
javac ./MyApp.java -classpath log4j-1.2.17.jar;./
```

run

```
java -classpath log4j-1.2.17.jar;./ MyApp
```

Comment: could you provide the ordinary way of compiling and running also

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Category

Answer (score 0):

Include current directory in java classpath

```
java -cp log4j-1.2.17.jar;. MyApp
```

[Why do you have to include current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706689/java-class-files-in-current-directory):

```
The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include "." in the new settings.
```

Answer (score 0):

Y need to include the local directory. If you want to do it in the current directory it would be something like:

```
javac -cp .;log4j-1.2.17.jar Bar
```