# running the .jar file of jalview

Tags: java

I am trying to get Jalview [1] running on my windows 7 system. The standard installation works without error but when starting (the .exe file) it I get "Windows error 2 occured while loading the Java VM". As this error is quite general I tried then

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jalview>java -jar jalview.jar
```

which leads to:

```
Java version: 1.8.0_121
x86 Windows 7 6.1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layo
ut
        at jalview.bin.Jalview.doMain(Jalview.java:210)
        at jalview.bin.Jalview.main(Jalview.java:180)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Layout
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

any ideas what is going wrong?

Thx
Morpheus

[1] http://www.jalview.org/Download

Comment: You don't have the log4j Libraries in the classpath ... look at this post for suggestions . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262015/specifying-log4j-in-classpath

Answer (score 0):

This error "*java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError*" occurs when there is a class missing in your respective packages.
I suggest please check if the class "Layout" is present at path : org/apache/log4j
If not then its correct that you have some missing files/libraries of log4j in the classpath.
Please vote and mark the solution if useful.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

First check that in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jalview\lib` the library `min-jabaws-client-*.jar` exists.

To run it from command line

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jalview
java -cp jalview.jar;lib/* jalview.bin.Jalview
```