# -cp ./ Why do I always have to manually include the CWD to the CP when running Java?

Tags: java, classpath, working-directory

I never used to have this problem and when I went to run Java programs (in a terminal) I would simply say,

```
    java className
```

and the program would run. But lately when I try this I get the error,

> could not find or load main class className

To fix this I've been adding `-cp ./` my curring working directory to the classpath and then the program runs. I'm not sure what to add to my environment variables so that the current working directory will *always* be on the class path thus avoiding this longer script,

```
    java -cp ./ className
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3706703/3299397) StackOverflow post the standard implementation from Oracle looks in the current working directory for the class name first.

(I am using Java 8 and Windows 8.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classpath, if not found on the command line, and not found in the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, [defaults to the current directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

> **-cp classpath**
>
> Specifies a list of directories, JAR files, and ZIP archives to search for class files. Separate class path entries with semicolons (;)
>
> Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the CLASSPATH environment variable.
>
> If -classpath and -cp are not used and CLASSPATH is not set, then the user class path consists of the current directory (.).

If you specify `-cp`, then you must explicitly include `.` (the current directory) in the classpath, or it will not be included.

If not using `-cp` doesn't work, but explicitly stating `-cp .` does work, then you must have the `CLASSPATH` environment variable defined, and it must not explicitly include `.`.  That would explain why overriding `CLASSPATH` by including `.` with the `-cp` option works.

Comment: I only specify `-cp` so that I can include `.`. What I'm getting at is how can I get back to simply running with `java className` because as of right now the only way for my program to run is with `java -cp ./ className`

Comment: Do you have a `CLASSPATH` environment variable defined?  Perhaps you do, but `.` isn't in the `CLASSPATH`.  That would explain why no `-cp` doesn't work, but `-cp .` does work.

Comment: I'm an idiot I didn't realize I could add `./` in my Environment Variable for `CLASSPATH`. Thank you the problem is solved.

Comment: Isn't your answer saying that `java wtv` and `java -cp . wtv` are the same?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Only if the environment variable isn't defined.  I'll need to make that more clear...