# Java Cannot "Could not find or load main class HW" after I change CLASSPATH

Tags: java, classpath

Things worked yesterday ,  I dont know what I did to break them

I'm trying to compile servlets , connect to MySQL DBs etc .
Problem is this.

I have a `HW.java` file which just prints Hello World ,
I compile it and run it , it works fine

Now say I need to use Servlet API methods in it 
So I do this

export CLASSPATH="/Users/User/tomcat.....servlet...api"

now when I try to run (compilation works perfectly ) after exporting CLASSPATH 
I get this

Could not find or load main class HW

Not only Servlet Programs , even a Hello World program doesnt run
Unless I CLear CLASSPATH by using export CLASSPATH=

Things worked fine before dont know what I broke , 
Please help

Comment: Don't forget to add the current directory to classpath : "."

Comment: Can you give me an exact example command

Comment: -classpath .:lib/somejar.jar:lib/someOtherJar.jar

Comment: Ok but how did things work before without doing all this ?

Comment: By default, current directory is in the classpath, UNLESS you declare the classpath on your own, which overwrites the default classpath.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706689/java-class-files-in-current-directory

Comment: I read that post but just  
export CLASSPATH="lib/somejar.jar:lib/someOtherJar.jar"  lib/someOtherJar.jar  and then running a .class file on the current dir worked yesterday :( how is that possible

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2592194

Answer (score 0):

You have to always remember to put class path with your class in the CLASSPATH as well.

```
export CLASSPATH="/Users/User/tomcat.....servlet...api":$CLASSPATH:/somedir/where/your/HW_class_is
```

And remember to put top dir where your package is declared. Let's say you have class

```
mypackage.mysubpackage.HW.class
```

inside dir

```
$HOME/test/mypackage/mysubpackage
```

you have to add:

```
$HOME/test/ to CLASSPATH
```