# Trouble running java app from cmd

Tags: java, javac

I have two files, app.java and test.java
They both reside in the same package, and they compile just fine with "javac app.java test.java"
Two class files are then created.
However, when I go to run them with the command "java app" because app has the main method, I get "Error: Could not find or load main class app"

app.java:

```
package working_directory;

public class app {

public app() {

}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    test testing = new test();
    System.out.println(testing.calculate(60));
}
}
```

This Is the test.java

```
package working_directory;

public class test {

public test() {

}

public int calculate(int x) {
    return (int) x * x * x;
}
}
```

Comment: We cannot debug code we cannot see.

Comment: There is no code to be seen. All the information that is problematic is given

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java class files in current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706689/java-class-files-in-current-directory)

Comment: There are four files in the directory, app.java, test.java, app.class, test.class

Comment: It works fine in an IDE, I am just having trouble manually running it through CMD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to choose the right path for compilation and running code:

```
D:\
 +--Folder(start cmd here)
       +---working_directory
                          +----app.java
                          +----test.java
```

**How to compile**

```
D:\Folder\>javac working_directory\*.java
```

**How to run**

```
D:\Folder\>java working_directory.app
```

Comment: This was my problem. I had started the cmd in the working_directory. "D:\Folder\>java working_directory.app" worked.

Answer (score 1):

To use the `java` command, you must specify the *fully qualified name* of the class you want run. This means that you need to specify the package name as well.

You should run this:

```
java working_directory.app
```

Since `working_directory` is the package name.

Comment: Tried, but same error. Error: Could not find or load main class working_directory.app

Comment: @laocak `working_directory` is the _actual_ name of your package right? If it is not, use the _actual_ name of the package.

Comment: yes, working_directory is the full name of the package and it is included in both files.

Comment: @laocak I got it. You need to go to the parent directory before running `java`. i.e. `cd ../`

Answer (score 0):

You have a package name declared in other words that's a folder. Your project should look like this then

```
C:\YourProject
 C:\YourProject\working_directory
  C:\YourProject\working_directory\app.java
```

Your Project starts at root level so it's `C:\YourProject` there you have to use the command line and type `java working_directory.app`

Comment: All files in the directory are lowercase, and match eachother

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a classpath, when running it from command line:

(for windows)

```
java -classpath . app
```

Comment: java -classpath . app
Error: Could not find or load main class app

Comment: @laocak, try to perform this command outside working_directory, as 
java -classpath . working_directory.app